# Can I change Icons?

Tags: icons

I want to change my icons on Ubuntu to another set of icons. Maybe Mac OS icons. Is there any way that I can change icons entirely, or just desktop environment (choose between them in login).

Answer (score 6):

Add PPA for mac theme and icon

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/macbuntu
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install macbuntu-os-icons-lts-v7
sudo apt-get install macbuntu-os-ithemes-lts-v7
```

Install unity-tweak-tool using:

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Launch `unity-tweak-tool` and select mac theme and icon.

Picture after applying theme and icons:

[image]